# Remove invalid index

Tags: apt

Whenever I'd run `sudo apt-get update` it always never ends well

```
...

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/qiana/main/source/Sources  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/qiana/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/qiana/main/binary-i386/Packages  HttpError404

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there some way to fix this and remove the missing index? I'm pretty sure I'm not even using it. This started happening the moment I ran `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`.

Comment: Was there a package that you were trying to get from the site deb.nodesource.com?

Comment: I checked out Software Resources and true enough there under __Additional Repositories__ was the problem. After deleting it everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the resulting Gedit, change all the lines with `https` to `http`.

Ex: `https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/qiana/main/source/Sources` to `http://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/qiana/main/source/Sources`

Then save and close the file

Then run an update.